# QGIS split line into segments on polygon

Tags: qgis, polygon, line, splitting

Is it possible in QGIS to split a line into segments given which polygon it falls within? I am using 2.8.

For example, a line that passes through three polygons will become three separate lines. Each time it crosses from one polygon into another it'd become a new line.

So in this case, where the green is a line, I would like to split it into three separate lines. Once for each time it crosses the black border of a polygon.

[image: Line to be split]

Comment: This is the basic geoprocessing operation called Intersection - You can find it under top menu: Vector / Geoprocessing tools / Intersect...

Answer (score 2):

**[QGIS 2.8]** Use the Intersect tool menu : "Vector / Geoprocessing tools / Intersect" *(from Miro's answer in comments)*

**[QGIS 2.18]** Use the Intersection Tool in the processing toolbox/panel :

[image: Intersect tool]

> This algorithm extracts the overlapping portions of
>   features in the Input and Intersect layers. Features in the
>   Intersection layer are assigned the attributes of the overlapping
>   features from both the Input and Intersect layers. Attributes are not
>   modified.